# Enable/Disable TextExpander using Script

Tags: text

I am trying to disable/enable textexpander using a single shortcut key. Text expander's preferences require using option, command and control together with a predefined shortcut key. Is there a way to bypass this using apple script and simply enable/or disable textexpander using a single shortcut key? Thanks.

Comment: Are there any keys left to use without Opt/Cmd/Ctrl/Shift?

Comment: I am trying to use the F19 key on the apple wired keyboard. Text expander has support for apple script using key words like 'enable expansion' but i am not sure how to use it in a script.

Comment: `expansion enabled` is a property, which AFAIK is read-only. Do you have other tools like Keyboard Maestro or similar?

Comment: yes i have keyboad maestro...any tips?

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, you don't need to press all those keys, just one of them. So ctrl-F19 or Shift-F19 would work. It's not the same as just using the one key, but it's slightly better that you don't have to press four keys, just two. And if you use the Control key there's a good chance you won't bump into many other keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, TextExpander has [Scriptable Preference Settings](https://textexpander.com/learn/using/snippets/scripting-textexpander/applescript-shellscript).

So, to disable, using the shell:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "TextExpander" to set expansion enabled to 0'
```

To enable:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "TextExpander" to set expansion enabled to 1'
```

There are many preferences you can access or change via AppleScript: `expansion enabled` is a boolean flag controlling whether expansion (and capitalization correction) is enabled.

[Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/), [Hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/) and [skhd](https://github.com/koekeishiya/skhd) are some of the many options you have to create a toggle command (and bind it to a keyboard shortcut).